# Power Automate filter date - first day of next month

Tags: power-automate

I'd like to filter a table in power automate thanks to the filter panel to get only data for the first day of the following month.

For instance, today is the 11th september. If I run the flow, I should get data starting 1st october (my column is called "Date d''entrée effective").

Please note that I do not want to use the Automate functions of excel, I'd like to get that done entirely with the flow of power automate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could determine the current month (by using [utcNow](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#utcNow) with the MM format) and just add 1 to it via an [add](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#add) function. Only exception would be December. In that case you just want to skip the add function.

Below is an example expression.
*The outputs is a string in the yyyy-MM-dd format, btw.*

```
if(equals(utcNow('MM'), '12'), concat(add(int(utcNow('yyyy')),1), '-01-01'), concat(utcNow('yyyy'), '-', formatnumber(add(int(utcNow('MM')),1), '00'), '-01'))
```

Comment: how can I integrate your line of code to my filter statement: @or(equals(item()?['Statut'], 'Pourvu'),equals(item()?['Statut'], 'Pourvu (attente date'))

Comment: Also, I have several dates columns, where can I specify which column it can use?

Comment: Can you give an example name of a date column name? This way I can amend the example for the filter Array action.

Comment: The name is "Date d''entrée effective". Thank you.

Comment: I assume that is the displayName of the field. Below is an example with an internal name (which I guessed). I would suggest to add the expression I shared earlier via an and to the existing expression of the where part of the Filter Array action. `@and(or(equals(item()?['Statut'], 'Pourvu'), equals(item()?['Statut'], 'Pourvu (attente date')), greaterorequals(item()['DateDEntreeEffective'], if(equals(utcNow('MM'), '12'), concat(add(int(utcNow('yyyy')),1), '-01-01'), concat(utcNow('yyyy'), '-', formatnumber(add(int(utcNow('MM')),1), '00'), '-01'))))`

Comment: thank you for your reply, I get the following error message:

Flow save failed with code 'WorkflowRunActionInputsInvalidProperty' and message 'The 'inputs' of workflow run action 'Filtrer_un_tableau_des_en_cours' of type 'Query' is not valid. Property 'where' must be a template language expression.'.